# How to disable birthday notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

On Facebook, notifications have started showing up for birthdays:

[image: Facebook birthdays notification]

These notifications are a waste of time, they are redundant with the birthday notification zone that already shows up on the news feed.

**QUESTION:** How to stop birthdays from generating a notification?

Greasemonkey/userscripts accepted if there is no easier solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the steps you should follow
**Settings**
[image]
**Notification**
[image]
**Birthday**
[image]

[image]
Note:You shouldn't use greasemonkey scripts for Facebook. Unless you read over the code to know what is actually happening. Very sensitive information and greasemonkey support has been removed as native from browsers for many with malicious intent. And the fact that notifications are provided as a server>client thing and the only way a script would stop them from showing up would be to edit the classes on the page.